# 400 bad request Send post request with txt file using httpclient

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use Apache httpclient to send the post request to my server.
The post request will send a text file to the server. And the server will do some operation with the content of that text file.

But I got 400 bad request.

```
final byte[] file = new byte[(int) flowFile.getSize()];
...

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
MultipartEntityBuilder entitybuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entitybuilder.addBinaryBody(fileName, file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, fileName);

HttpEntity mutiPartHttpEntity = entitybuilder.build();
RequestBuilder reqbuilder = RequestBuilder.post("http://0.0.0.0:3333/predict");

reqbuilder.setEntity(mutiPartHttpEntity);

HttpUriRequest multipartRequest = reqbuilder.build();

HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(multipartRequest);
StatusLine status = httpresponse.getStatusLine();
```

How can I fix that? Is anything wrong with my code to add the text file?

Comment: Post the exception from your java backend server. Have you tried with 127.0.0.1 instead 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @Davide Yes, my server can get this type of POST request in postman

Comment: Well, probably you encounter the OPTIONS problem. The preflight request (OPTIONS) is rejected and automatically the POST gives you a 400 back. You need to allow the OPTIONS request insides your project. Are you using spring boot?

Comment: @Davide Thank you!